# Boolean modifier applied to imported obj

Tags: modifiers, import

I've seen that Blender has some difficulties handling boolean operations such as difference, as discussed for example here:

[Boolean modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114896/boolean-modifier)

However, I noticed a strange behavior of the "boolean difference" operator. In the image below, there are two boxes. The big one is generated as a "cube" inside Blender. The smaller is imported from a .obj file. The two wireframes look similar. Then, I "subtract" a sphere from each of them.

[image: Here is the result]

The known artifacts appear only on the imported box, not on the cube generated internally. I already played with the "auto smooth" property and with the "custom split normals" without changing the result. Is it due to a different internal structure of the two boxes or it depends on attributes? How can I make the behavior of the operation on the imported objects equal to the internally generated cube?

Comment: How the imported geometry looks like? I guess it's just a mess of triangles hence the result... Try to convert to quads and recalculate the normals before adding the boolean modifier.

Comment: The imported box is composed of six rectangular faces. This is confirmed by looking at the wireframe. I also tried with triangular faces, i.e. each face is split into two triangles. No difference.

Comment: Does the outcome is the same when using a same sized box created in blender?

Comment: Try to change the shading for the smaller cube to flat shading Or click on the flipped Green triangle in the properties window and expand the "Normals" panel the check on "Auto Smooth".

Comment: The box size does not matter. I tried with equal sizes, one bigger or the other bigger. Also the dimension of the sphere does not matter.

Comment: I already tried to play with "auto smooth" without any change. Could you please let me know where the flag "flat shading" is?